# INSERT statement affects 1 row, but the VS Server Explorer shows that it doesn't actually update the SQL CE database

Tags: c#, insert, sql-server-ce

I've checked other Stack Overflow questions to find answers, but I just can't find a solution to this. I am trying to insert string data into a SQL CE (local database).

I can read from the database, but I cannot insert data, regardless of whether I hard-code it or try to add it with parameters.

The table to be modified is called `users`. It has 3 columns: `ID`, `name`, `email`.

Here is the code I am using:

```
string connection = Properties.Settings.Default.LocalDBConnectionString;

using (var con = new SqlCeConnection(connection))
{
    con.Open();

    // (I also tried adding with parameters but couldn't get it working.)
    using (var com = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO users (name, email) " +
                                      "VALUES (N'jimmy', N'email@jim.com')", con))
    {
        int numRowsAffected = com.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // This returns '1 row affected' but doesn't actually update the database
        Console.WriteLine(numRowsAffected);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Although the Console outputs `1`, because 1 row is affected, when I go back into the database and check, it has not inserted the new data.

I was following [this tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlce), but only the Read works, the Insert or write doesn't work.

I also found this similar [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366123/sql-ce-3-5-writing-to-a-database), but using parameters, still couldn't get it to work.

---

**Edit:**

My connection string is:

```
Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LocalDB.sdf
```

I don't know how to find the Build Settings, it is a Local Database I created within the console application solution, It is stored in the project directory.

I am in "Debug" configuration if that helps?

---

Here is another example I found [on the internet](http://www.mikeborozdin.com/post/Introducing-Microsoft-SQL-Server-Compact-Edition-%28Part-I%29.aspx):

```
SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.LocalDBConnectionString);
con.Open();

SqlCeCommand comInsert = new SqlCeCommand ("INSERT INTO users(name, email) VALUES('value 1', 'value 2')", con);
comInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();

SqlCeCommand comSelect = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM users", con);
SqlCeDataReader reader = comSelect.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", reader["name"], reader["email"]);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

con.Close();
```

I just copied and pasted this in, and changed the main variables. This example temporarily inserts the data, but when I go to Visual Studio's Server Explorer and view the table, it hasn't updated.

Comment: Does it not effect the database during the current run of your application (i.e. what happens if you breakpoint readkey and execute SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'jimmy'), or does it only not persist between runs? If it's not persisting between runs, where is your database file stored, is it a resource of your project (and if so what are the build settings for that file), and what does your connection string look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that the database you `INSERT` into and the database you're looking at with Server Explorer are the same one?

Remember, we're talking about a file-based DB here (SQL Server *CE*). So **it could be that you're `INSERT`ing into a copy of your DB and then look at the (unchanged) original.**

- Is the DB file part of your solution? If so, does it get copied to the output directory (e.g. `bin\Debug`)? Check the properties of the corresponding solution item, like in the screenshot below (sorry for it being in German):

  [image: Screenshot showing a 'Local Database' project item and its 'Copy to output directory' property setting]
- Where exactly does `DataDirectory` in the connection string point to? If you're not sure, replace it with something absolute for the time being and see if that solves your problem.

Make double sure that your connection string really points to the database you're looking at with Server Explorer!

Comment: Your Right!, I was looking at the wrong DB, I had one db in the project file and another in the bin/debug folder, which was the one I was writing to. What would I have to do to change all the paths to just one DB located in the bin/debug directory?

Comment: Hmm... I can't quite remember what I ended up doing when I had the same problem, but: I'd suggest you set up your DB file solution item so that it will be copied to the output ("`bin`") directory, and change the connection string to something like `Data Source=.\LocalDB.sdf`. (During program execution, your `bin` directory will be the current directory.) Or you designate any other directory and have the DB file copied there & the connection string pointing there. You can use `System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder` to manipulate parts of a connection string at runtime.

Comment: Here is more info regarding this issue from MSDN for anyone else with the same problem.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smartclientdata/archive/2005/08/26/456886.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is here: `Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LocalDB.sdf`
When you run your program from Visual Studio it connects to a database in the Debug (or Release) directory not to that database you have in the project's directory. So, try to use full path instead of `Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LocalDB.sdf`, try something like this: `Data Source=C:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\MyProject\LocalDB.sdf`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I checked my solution explorer connection string and pasted in code file and my problem was solved so make changes to your connection string.